# Using Chef to create config files

Tags: weblogic, configuration-files, chef-infra

The project I am on is considering bringing in Chef to help manage deployments. That seems perfectly reasonable as we have had issues configuring new machines/environments. However, they are now asking me to use Chef as a mechanism to create config files for a bunch of different environments and I am wondering if it is the right tool for the job. I've googled around quite a bit and haven't seen anyone using it like this...

I have an xml file with a ton of options like the following (it is used to configure weblogic):

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <name>MANAGED_SERVER_1</name>
        <listenAddress>machine46</listenAddress>
        <listenPort>65501</listenPort>
        <listenPortSecure>65502</listenPortSecure>
        <classpath>/example/test/test.jar....
```

We have 12 different environments, each with different ports, names, etc. That would mean creating 12 separate xml files, writing something to do a search and replace in one master xml for each environment, or potentially using Chef.

Will Chef serve this purpose? Is this even really what is SHOULD be used for? It's kind of being shoved down our throats at the moment.

An example of modifying/creating multiple config files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should generate the files completely from ERB templates (on the designated nodes/machines managed by chef) instead of rewriting a concrete master file

Answer (score 2):

Chef (and it's likes) are perfect for these kind of things, and a lot of chef cookbooks already does configuration file generation. Typically, you would include a template (it's actually erb files, as mentioned in a comment) in your cookbook, and your recipe would use the environment specific variables for the server and [data bags](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html), as input for the template to generate the environment specific configuration file. By experience I'd say that looking at the source code for some existing data bags are the best way to learn how to do this.